# How to prevent animation on page load CSS

Tags: html, css, animation

I want to do an increase animation by pressing a button. There is a problem with this code, because the animation starts when the page is loaded. How can you block the start of the animation while the page is loading. Is it possible? Please help me.

```
button:not(:active){
  animation: 2s anim;
}
@keyframes anim {
  50% {
    transform: scale(2);
  }
}
```

```
<button>CLICK!</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

Hard-coding an animation-delay is not a good idea since the time the page needs to load is not fixed and depends on multiple factors.

You should use JS oder jQuery to monitor the loading state of your page.

JS: [document.readyState](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/readyState)

jQuery: `$(document).ready(function()` or `$(window).load(function()`

Answer (score 0):

add `animation-delay: 2s;` to the `button:not(:active)` code. This might help let the page load before the animation starts.

Comment: But after pressing the button I will have to wait 2s for the animation and it will be done immediately.

Comment: Do you wan't the animation to only happen once the button is clicked?

Comment: I want the animation to be performed anyway when the button is pressed, but block it while the page is loading, I want to do it in CSS.

Answer (score 0):

You may consider `:focus` instead and do it like below but to run the animation again you will need to click outside the button to disable the focus

```css
button:focus{
  animation: 2s anim;
}
@keyframes anim {
  50% {
    transform: scale(2);
  }
}
```

```html
<button>CLICK!</button>
```

Answer (score -1):

If you want to start animation on the click of button you just need to changes your css as follows

I think it would work.

```
button:active{
   animation: 2s anim;
}
```